# Close Remote Login (windows 7) without ending session

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, session-manager

I am running a audio stream server from a windows 7 machine. I need to manage the playlist after remotely logging in into the machine. When I end the remote login session, the server stops and hence there is no streaming. I need to manage the playlist remotely. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't end the session. Disconnect by closing the RDP client. Windows' Terminal Server will continue hosting the session, and you can reconnect to it by logging back in over RDP or locally on the machine.

Comment: Unless there is a (low) [time limit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791741) set as policy to logoff a disconnected user.

Comment: @Rik +1 The more I know. I've always used console sessions myself, so I haven't run into that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Yeah, that's working fine and I already knew this. The problem is when I clost the remote session, the Shoutcast Source DSP plugin disconnects from the DNAS server. The player keeps running but the streaming stops. I guess I'll post a question on the SHOUTcast forum. Thanks